# Entity Framework - customize navigation properties to abstract joins

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have looked through similar questions here, but not seen this specific scenario.

Using EF 6 Code First, I have three tables, A, B and C.  The relationship is A => B = 1:M, and B=>C = 1:1

The end result in this schema is that there is an implicit 1:M between A and C.

I do NOT want the consumer of the Entity Framework model to know about B.  Ideally they would have a 1:M Navigation property from A to C (and I'd like to be able to surface this Entity Model through Web API and OData as IQueryable)

How could I do this?

If I add a custom [NotMapped] property to A which a collection of C, I have no way of populating C within the getter of that property because the entity doesn't know about its context.

Anyone have any ideas as to how to implement an IQueryable where A has a navigation property to C and B is 'abstracted' out of existence?

**EDIT**

Attempted to put the following into the code first entity A:

```
[NotMapped]
public ICollection<C> Cs
{
        get { return this.Bs.Select(b => b.C) as ICollection<C>; }
}
```

But got this error:
The navigation property 'C' is not a declared property on type 'A'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model and that it is a valid navigation property.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by `implicit 1:M between A and C.` ? Why don't you want to go from A to C through B ?

Comment: I'm using a legacy schema that I cannot alter.  But the consumers of my services have no need to know anything about the details of the joins between these tables.  They really only care about the relationship between A and C.  Entity Framework should be able to give the consumer a queryable Entity Model which hides the details of the joins that have to happen.  If I were doing Model-First, I'd probably look at using a DefiningQuery for this.

Comment: if you want to get a single A that contains all C, you just need to add Cs property with `[NotMapped]` attribute then do select query, `var a = db.As.Include(a => a.Bs.Select(b => b.C)).FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == key);` and fill the `Cs`, `a.Cs = a.Bs.Select(b => b.C);`

Comment: Yuliam, appreciate the query.  That definitely works for the consumer of the model, but if I'm reading your code right, it still requires the EF model consumer to know about B.  There's no place you can tell EF that when the C Property is accessed, it should run that query to fill it.  The client would be doing so, correct?

Comment: so what you meant by consumer is any code that uses dbcontext (odata controller) ? not the ones that access odata service (`http://localhost/Products`) ?

Comment: Yes, nothing outside my DAL should see table B.  Tried adding a custom Non-Mapped property and even specifying HasMany() in the fluent API, in addition. `[NotMapped] public ICollection<C> Cs { get { return this.Bs.Select(x => x.C) as ICollection<C>; } }`

But I get the error 
The navigation property 'Cs' is not a declared property on type 'A'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model and that it is a valid navigation property.

Comment: hmm `[NotMapped]` should work as [it seems very simple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#NotMapped) in the documentation, no other configurations required, perhaps it was `B` that has problem, take a look [similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773334/the-navigation-property-senderid-is-not-a-declared-property-on-type-conversat)

Comment: I'm revisiting this topic right now, as I still haven't really found a good solution.  I think I'm trying to have my cake and eat it, too.  What I would like is the ability to abstract certain joins and relationships to hide them from the EF consumer, but at the same time I'd like to keep composability intact.  The problem is, if I create a custom collection property, it has to be an ICollection, which is not a queryable result, and it can't be used as part of a LINQ query to generate a nice single SQL to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.

```
public static class OrderDAL
{
    public static Order Get(int key)
    {
        using (var context = new AppContext())
        {
            var order = context.Orders.Include(a => a.OrderDetails.Select(b => b.Information)).FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == key);
            // Fills C.
            order.OrderDetailAdditionalInformation = order.OrderDetails.Select(b => b.Information).ToArray();
            // Hides information about B.
            foreach (var information in order.OrderDetailAdditionalInformation)
            { information.OrderDetail = null; }
            order.OrderDetails = null;
            return order;
        }
    }
}
public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
// A
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<OrderDetailAdditionalInformation> OrderDetailAdditionalInformation { get; set; }
}
// B, one A many B
public class OrderDetail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public OrderDetailAdditionalInformation Information { get; set; }
}
// C, one B one C
public class OrderDetailAdditionalInformation
{
    [ForeignKey("OrderDetail")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Long { get; set; }
    public OrderDetail OrderDetail { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the above.  The example will in fact help hide table B.  Where I'm trying to figure out where this fits in is in a Web API or OData project example, where I have a controller for Table A, and I wnat to do this:

`http://myService/odata/A(12345)/Cs`

The AController would get called for this, but because the Cs is not a navigation property (you just show it as a static method), I see no way this query could be made to work, so it feels like I'm still very limited in my extraction.

Comment: @RandyMagruder, I think u're right, `Cs` is not part of the graph, doing query against it directly will not work